# License conflicts in nuxt

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, nuxt.js

I'm facing an issue when I build my nuxt app.
When I run 'npm run build', it says:
`WARNING in The comment file "LICENSES" conflicts with an existing asset, this may lead to code corruption, please use a different name`.

Here's my package.json file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "marked": "^0.8.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-fragment": "^1.5.1",
    "vue-pdf": "^4.0.7",
    "vue-slick-carousel": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-youtube": "^1.4.0",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^1.0.1",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^1.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.10.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": ">=0.4.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "license-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.4",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4"
  }
}
```

Here's the console output:
[image]

How can I know which packages conflict with license files?

Comment: without the output of the console its hard to guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the culprit was the terser webpack plugin. Disabling the terser.extractComments option in build config under nuxt.config.js got rid of the warnings.

`nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
    // ... other nuxt config,
    build: {
        // ... other build config,
        terser: {
            extractComments: false // default was LICENSES
        }
    }
}
```